# What are considerations for an IRC §501(c)(3) donating to an IRC §501(c)(7) Social Club?

Tags: united-states, irs, non-profit

What fiscal considerations may there be for a §501(c)(3) that, consistent with promotion of it's mission, wishes to make a donation to a for-profit corporation or a §501(c)(7) social club?

Clearly the amount is not "tax deductible", but that's not a concern for the (c)(3) anyway.

Comment: As you point out, the cross-donation has to clearly be  furthering the 501c3's mission. If it is, and is reasonably efficient about doing so, I don't expect any more trouble than it you paid a purely commercial organization the same amount to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Although it may trigger questions from the IRS as to why a charity needs to spend money on country clubs...